# VB Net Quotes in a string

Tags: string, vb.net, quotes

I need quotes in a string in VB Net.

```
c = C:\test.doc
```

How can I realize that the string looks like:

```
PrintFile /File="C:\test.doc" /OutputFile="C:\test.pdf"
```

online I read that I have to double the quotes...
but this doesn't work:

```
" PrintFile /File=""" & c & """ /OutputFile=""" & pfadFertig & pdfName & ".pdf"""
```

How can I get `c` and `pfadFertig & pdfName & .pdf` appear in quotes?

Comment: I ran your code guessing at values for _c_, _pfadFertig_, and _pdfName_. Everything looks fine to me, with the output of: PrintFile /File="C:\test.doc" /OutputFile="C:\test.pdf".

Comment: Can you edit the question to include the values you have for the variables and what output you are getting?

Comment: It is fine.  If you look at it with the debugger then click the spyglass icon and select "Text Visualizer" to see the actual string.

Answer (score 4):

You do indeed have to double the quotes. This is a great example of why you should use `String.Format` or, even better, string interpolation. Using concatenation operators (`&`) already makes your code harder to read but with all the extra quotes, it's harder still. Do this:

```vb
Dim str = $"PrintFile /File=""{c}"" /OutputFile=""{pfadFertig}{pdfName}.pdf"""
```

It's obviously much easier to read.

Also I suspect that `pfadFertig` is a folder path, in which case you should be using `Path.Combine` to create the file path:

```vb
Dim str = $"PrintFile /File=""{c}"" /OutputFile=""{Path.Combine(pfadFertig, pdfName)}.pdf"""
```

`Path.Combine` will ensure the correct number of slashes regardless of what trailing or leading slashes are included in the inputs, so you can never make a mistake. In this case, I could probably excuse one concatenation operator as it may seem more natural:

```vb
Dim str = $"PrintFile /File=""{c}"" /OutputFile=""{Path.Combine(pfadFertig, pdfName & ".pdf")}"""
```